# Problem running Cake shell in cronjob

Tags: php, bash, cron, cakephp-1.3

I followed the instructions on http://book.cakephp.org/view/1110/Running-Shells-as-cronjobs
and I still ran into a strange problem while running my shell in
cronjob.

I am getting error when I try to use model in the shell:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_query() in /home/cake1.3.6/cake/libs/model/datasources/dbo/dbo_mysql.php on line 600

The shell runs fine if I just fire it up manually.
Why can't PHP see mysql_query() when it's done in a shell via cronjob?

I found out that I can fix the problem by calling php with its
absolute path in cake/console/cake:

From:

```
exec php -q ${LIB}cake.php -working "${APP}" "$@"
```

To:

```
exec /usr/local/bin/php -q ${LIB}cake.php -working "${APP}" "$@"
```

However, I do not like that solution because it changes Cake core.

Anyone any clue?

**EDIT**
There was one answer from someone earlier and I replied saying that I was sure there was one copy of PHP binary but it turned out I was wrong! What happened to that answer as it just disappeared? Whoever that was please put the answer back and I'll give you point. Thanks!

Comment: The environment for cron and cli might different, this could lead to the problem

Comment: @ajreal: The OP would like you to restore your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relative path could be refer to other PHP binary instead.
You can do a test

```
php -m | grep mysql -i
```

**AND**

```
/usr/local/bin/php -m | grep mysql -i
```

If the first one does not match, it explain why you getting a undefined fatal error.

Comment: They both show mysql and mysqli. I also am positive that there is only one copy of php binary which I compiled in /usr/local/bin. Thanks!